# Are there other ways to find an unused port number

Tags: tcl

I need to run a web server written in Tcl which by default relies on a hard-coded port number to listen on, which though I'm afraid could cause it to fail if that port were already in use.  It does allow you to pass in a port number as a parameter, but that could just result in the same problem if you haven't assured yourself it's an unused port.

I've devised the following way to get an unused port which seems like it could work (see next to last line), and the chance for failure (i.e. the port becomes used during the intervening time) seems much more slim than just relying on a randomly chosen port number.  Still though I'm not entirely satisfied and am wondering what other ways there might be to achieve this objective.

```
proc noop {chan addr port} {
}
set chan [socket -server noop 0]
set sockname [chan configure $chan -sockname]
chan close $chan
set port [lindex $sockname end]         ;# e.g. 51922
set chan2 [socket -server noop $port]   ;# test re-usability of port
chan close $chan2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really all that much you can do as theoretically a socket could be opened at any point when you're not holding it open yourself, but staying out of the ephemeral port range (i.e., ports from 32768 (0x8000) upwards to 65535 (0xFFFF)) will help as then you won't get into problems with the automatically-assigned ports for the client side of TCP connections.

The usual port numbers for a local webserver that's being run as a normal user are 8000 and 8080 (and 8443 for HTTPS) though the actual port number is often immaterial. The key is that you usually plan such ports out as part of the overall plan for the machine; you can have a pretty good idea then that nothing is going to interfere, as you have control of the system. VMs make this all quite a bit simpler (and in full deployment scenarios, you use an apache or nginx proxy to make everything appear behind the system-protected ports 80 and 443).

Alternatively, you make the real system open the pseudo-port 0 (as in your script) then report what port it was actually assigned before continuing to service that port for real. That's a trivial extension to what you do now… on one level, but requires that your entire system be set up for non-constant port numbers. That can be difficult, and is usually only useful for testing frameworks (Tcl's own test suite uses this trick quite a bit) or where the underlying protocol has been designed from the ground up to work that way.

Comment: I'm writing this software to run on other peoples' machines so I can't know what ports they may or may not be using.  I am however going to modify the source code of the server (it's my own git fork of it anyway) and apply the approach from the third paragraph, and as for the non-constant port number, I plan to output it to a scratch file.

Comment: From what I read (and maybe I misunderstood), another strategy might be to use `SO_REUSEPORT` on the first, sentinel `socket -server` call, then `socket -server` a second time, after having sniffed the port, to serve the port for real. Benefit of SO_REUSEPORT is that the sentinal socket will remain bound, unless closed explicitly, and avoid any possible race condition. Alas, from the script level, `socket -server -reuseport 1` is only available on Tcl 8.7, IIRC.